# MyPy can't find types for my local package

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-poetry

I have two python packages. One is a util library, and one is an application that will use the util library (eventually I will have more apps sharing the library.

I am using poetry for both, and the app specifies the common library as a dependency using the `path` and `develop` properties.

For example, my layout looks something like this:

```
- common/
   - common/
      - __init__.py
      - py.typed
   - pyproject.toml

- myapp/
   - myapp/
      - __init__.py
      - py.typed
   - pyproject.toml
```

And the `myapp\pyproject.toml` looks something like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "myapp"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
common = { path = "../common", develop = true }

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
mypy = "^0.910"
flake8 = "^4.0.1"
black = {version = "^21.12b0", allow-prereleases = true}
pytest = "^6.2.5"
pytest-cov = "^3.0.0"
pytest-mock = "^3.6.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I run `mypy` on `myapp` I get something like:

```
myapp/__init__.py:1:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "common"  [import]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the "util" package has type hints, you'll want to add a `py.typed` file to it (in the root directory of the package) so mypy understands it comes with type hints. `py.typed` should be empty, it's just a flag file.

If your package does *not* have type hints, then you'd have to add stubs files (`.pyi`).

More details: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#creating-pep-561-compatible-packages

Comment: My util/common package has a py.typed file (see directory structure above). Is it in the wrong location? I tried moving it one directory up and it didn’t work either.

Comment: sorry, I had missed that. I suspect `py.typed` works for _installed_ packages, so you might want to try installing the package in `--editable` mode: `cd <path-to-package>/common` `pip install -e ./`

Comment: Did you ever happen to solve this? I have the same issue and can't find anything online about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue in mypy, where py.typed is not recognized in editable installs: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13392

Pyright has some workarounds, which work in mypy also: https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/import-resolution?id=editable-installs

For setuptools try to force the legacy behavior (compat mode) with:

```
pip install -e . --config-settings editable_mode=compat
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me: Add your library's path to the `MYPYPATH` environment variable:

```bash
export MYPYPATH=$MYPYPATH:path/to/common
```

You can set this in your bash profile, if desired. I don't know if there's a cleaner way to make mypy detect such local packages automatically. [The documentation says](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#cannot-find-implementation-or-library-stub):

> ## Cannot find implementation or library stub
>
> If you are getting a `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module` error, this means mypy was not able to find the module you are trying to import, whether it comes bundled with type hints or not. If you are getting this error, try:
>
> 2. Reading the [How imports are found](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#finding-imports) section below to make sure you understand how exactly mypy searches for and finds modules and modify how you’re invoking mypy accordingly.
> 3. Directly specifying the directory containing the module you want to type check from the command line, by using the [`mypy_path`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-mypy_path) or [`files`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-files) config file options, or by using the `MYPYPATH` environment variable.